# How to parse the values and assign to my local variable in windows bash?

Tags: windows, bash

I have a json file

```
  input= {
    "credentials": {
        "accessKeyId": "123456789",
        "secretAccessKey": "654321",
        "sessionToken": "valuedummy",
        "expiration": "201925"
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse the value and assign to a local variable using windows bash.

What I am trying to achieve is:

Assign the values to my local variables a,b,c,d

```
a=123456789
b=654321
c=valuedummy
d=201925
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

jq is a reasonable approach:

```
a=$( jq -r  .credentials.accessKeyId   input )
```

where input is this file:

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "accessKeyId": "123456789",
        "secretAccessKey": "654321",
        "sessionToken": "valuedummy",
        "expiration": "201925"
    }
}
```

Comment: :Thaanks for your reply, i should not install jq package. i want to achieve without installing any packages

Comment: You ok with python?  Determine if  python -mjson.tool works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use tools that are meant to parse JSON, such as `jq`. You won't be able to do it reliably with `sed`, `awk` etc.:

```
$ cat file
{
    "credentials": {
        "accessKeyId": "123456789",
        "secretAccessKey": "654321",
        "sessionToken": "valuedummy",
        "expiration": "201925"
    }
}

$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=0 var=(a b c d)
while IFS= read -rd '' line; do
    printf -v "${var[i++]:-tmp}" "$line"
done < <(jq -j '.credentials | to_entries[] | (.value + "\u0000")' file)

declare -p a b c d

$ ./script
declare -- a="123456789"
declare -- b="654321"
declare -- c="valuedummy"
declare -- d="201925"
```

Answer (score 0):

A non jq answer, but requires json package and python (typically installed with standard distributions):

```
a=$( python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["credentials"]["accessKeyId"])' <input )
```

Edit:  Here is a slightly more general answer (IMHO):

```
$ cat input
{
    "credentials": {
        "accessKeyId": "123456789",
        "secretAccessKey": "654321",
        "sessionToken": "valuedummy",
        "expiration": "201925"
    }
}


$ cat json2env 
eval $( 
python -c '
import sys, json

for (k,v) in (json.load(sys.stdin)["'$1'"]).items(): 
    print(k + "=" + v)
' < $2  
)

$ . json2env credentials input
$ echo $accessKeyId 
123456789
$ echo $secretAccessKey 
654321
```

It's slightly more general in that it will accept any json of a similar format ( dictionary containing a dictionary ) .    I simply parameterized the dictionary attribute.

The python script basically prints all the name value pairs in the specified attribute ( in your case, "credentials" ).  The name is used as the variable name.  This is convenient but I suspect there are issues there with some symbols that may be acceptable in key names but not in variable names.